# I am trying to renew my facebook access token for posting on my wall automatically but getting null exception why?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get a new access token for posting on my walla automatic each some minutes.
Is this a good way ?
Im getting null exception. 
The exception is on the line: var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
{
    string code = "";
    var responsePost = "";
    try
    {
        //create the facebook account object
        var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = message;
        responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("feed", parameters).ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        if (request.QueryString["code"] != null)
           {
            code = request.QueryString["code"].ToString();
            GetAccessTokenFromCode("", "", "https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=535075181%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname",code);
           }
        responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
    }
    return responsePost;
}



public string GetAccessTokenFromCode(string AppID, string AppSecret, string RedirectURL, string Code)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    string u2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" + AppID + "&redirect_uri=" + RedirectURL + "&client_secret=" + AppSecret + "&code=" + Code + "&state=anytexthere";
    string access = wc.DownloadString(u2);
    access = access.Substring(access.IndexOf("access_token") + 13);
    if (access.Contains("&"))
    {
        string accesstoken = access.Substring(0, access.IndexOf("&"));
        return accesstoken;
    }

    return access;

}
```

Im getting null on this line:

```
var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
```

EDIT**

This is the original exception message: (OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: Session has expired on 12 פברואר 2014 09:00. The current time is 13 פברואר 2014 00:52.

This is the full original exception message:

```
Facebook.FacebookOAuthException was caught
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=(OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: Session has expired on 12 פברואר 2014 09:00. The current time is 13 פברואר 2014 00:52.
  Source=Facebook
  ErrorCode=190
  ErrorSubcode=463
  ErrorType=OAuthException
  StackTrace:
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType)
       at Facebook.FacebookClient.Post(String path, Object parameters)
       at ScrollLabelTest.Form1.PostFacebookWall(String accessToken, String message) in e:\scrolllabel\ScrollLabel\ScrollLabel\Form1.cs:line 268
  InnerException:
```

So i tried i want to renew the access token automatic each time it had expired.

Comment: Since you are encountering a ``NullReferenceException`` in your ``catch`` block something must have gotten you in there in the first place. What is the original exception?

Comment: Zache the original exception was that my access token i used to post on my was has expired. So i want to renew it get a new one automatic and use the new access token code.

Comment: Zache this is the original exception message: (OAuthException - #190) Error validating access token: Session has expired on 12 פברואר 2014 09:00. The current time is 13 פברואר 2014 00:52.

Comment: Zache updated my question with the full original exception. Since it has expired i want to renew get new access token automatic each time it has expired so i can keep post messages on my wall.

Comment: Now I understand what you are after. rt2800 is correct in that there isn't a Current HttpContext in a WinForms application. Getting a new token automatically doesn't seem like an easy task, but I suggest you look into these resources: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot get `HttpContext` in a winform. Find other ways to get `code`